# PHP change locale settings?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, locale, currency

is there any way to edit/change the default locale setting in `localeconv()`?

I would like to use the the `money_format` function, and it works fine, but the locales for my language/region are not correct.

To be more precise, for Croatia, we use the currency symbol after the number, not before like set in local values?

Are there any ways I can edit this? Or at least manually check, change values, and send new values to `setlocale()`?

Working on shared hosting btw.

Comment: And what's wrong with http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with setlocale. Only that it accepts just the language strings as a parameter. And therefore loads the incorrect default values for my language

Comment: Have you looked into i18n PHP extension?

Comment: @Ethan: no, but ill check it out. Actually i18n is not what I'm looking for, I already got it covered with kohana. But anyway ill have a look

Comment: Kohana's i18n is technically just a framework for localization, where you provide translations (looks like). The PHP extenstion provides methods for localized time/date/currency, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I made it work with my own replacement of the `money_format()` function.
It is basically copy-paste from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#refsect1-function.money-format-examples) with added parameters for *forceRight* and *noSpace*

```
class Helper_Locales
{
    public static function formatNumber($number, $isMoney=false, $forceRight=false, $noSpace=false) {
        $lg = isset($lg) ? $lg : setlocale(LC_MONETARY, '0');
        $ret = setLocale(LC_ALL, $lg);
        setLocale(LC_TIME, 'Europe/Paris');
        if ($ret===FALSE) {
            echo "Language '$lg' is not supported by this system.\n";
            return;
        }
        $LocaleConfig = localeConv();
        forEach($LocaleConfig as $key => $val) $$key = $val;

        // Sign specifications:
        if ($number>=0) {
            $sign = $positive_sign;
            $sign_posn = $p_sign_posn;
            $sep_by_space = $p_sep_by_space;
            $cs_precedes = $p_cs_precedes;
        } else {
            $sign = $negative_sign;
            $sign_posn = $n_sign_posn;
            $sep_by_space = $n_sep_by_space;
            $cs_precedes = $n_cs_precedes;
        }

        // Number format:
        $n = number_format(abs($number), $frac_digits,
            $decimal_point, $thousands_sep);
        $n = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $n);
        switch($sign_posn) {
            case 0: $n = "($n)"; break;
            case 1: $n = "$sign$n"; break;
            case 2: $n = "$n$sign"; break;
            case 3: $n = "$sign$n"; break;
            case 4: $n = "$n$sign"; break;
            default: $n = "$n [error sign_posn=$sign_posn&nbsp;!]";
        }

        // Currency format:
        $currency_symbol = strtolower($currency_symbol);
        $m = number_format(abs($number), $frac_digits,
            $mon_decimal_point, $mon_thousands_sep);
        if ($sep_by_space && !$noSpace) $space = ' '; else $space = '';
        if ($cs_precedes && !$forceRight) $m = "$currency_symbol$space$m";
        else $m = "$m$space$currency_symbol";
        $m = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $m);
        switch($sign_posn) {
            case 0: $m = "($m)"; break;
            case 1: $m = "$sign$m"; break;
            case 2: $m = "$m$sign"; break;
            case 3: $m = "$sign$m"; break;
            case 4: $m = "$m$sign"; break;
            default: $m = "$m [error sign_posn=$sign_posn&nbsp;!]";
        }
        if ($isMoney) return $m; else return $n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`number_format()` has nothing to do with currency symbols, you probably meant `money_format()`, but ... well - just use `number_format()` and append whatever currency symbol you want to the return value.

Comment: i think ill just make my own money_format function, which accepts additional parameters like $foreceSymbolRight etc.